# C#, Unity - List<> (Argument is out of range...)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple spawn script. I have problem because I wanted to make dynamic array, and I stopped.

The problem is I have now this error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name:
>   index
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.GameObject].CheckIndex (Int32 index) ...

code:

```
public float spawnTime = 5f;
public float spawnDelay = 1f;      
public int enemyID = 0;

public List<GameObject> enemy = new List<GameObject>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    InvokeRepeating("Spawn", spawnDelay, spawnTime);
}

void Spawn ()
{
    Debug.Log (enemyID);
    enemy[enemyID] = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Enemies/Enemy"), new Vector3 (0, 3, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; // this is a problematic line, exactly this -> enemy[enemyID]
    enemyID++;
}
```

Comment: Unless you call 'Add', 'enemy' is an empty list and any index is out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your list is empty at the moment and has `enemy.length == 0`, hence index 0 of your list is not defined.

To dynamically add items to your list call `enemy.Add(Instantiate(...))`

Comment: **solution :** i change that to this

enemy.Add ( Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Enemies/Enemy"),new Vector3 (0, 3, 0) ,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject);

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can´t access a `List` with the indexer brackets `[]` before the given index has been initialized!

To add an element to a `List`you have to use `enemy.add(gameobject)`